# using nunit with visual web developer 2008 express

Tags: c#, nunit, visual-web-developer

I'm experimenting with potentially using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express for a project, but since the Express edition doesn't support the publish feature and since the ide also does not create any *proj files, how can I use the nunit gui to run my tests?

Comment: It may be worth noting that there is a difference between a Web Site project and a Web Application project. A Web Site does not use the regular project system but a Web Application project does so (IIRC) you can not create secondary projects in a Web Site as there is no root solution node.

Comment: There is a root solution node in all my web _site_ projects.  Many of them indeed have secondary projects.

Answer (score 4):

The approach I would take is move as much business logic as you can into a Class Library, and have your website use this Class Library and your unit tests test that Class Library.

Answer (score 1):

Your unit tests should reside in a separate project from the main project, and be a class library as well. From there, you can simply build your test project, and then open up the generated DLL in the NUnit GUI to run the tests.

I also second Andrew's suggestion on moving the business logic to a separate DLL away from the web project you create, as it makes it easier to unit test and re-use.